# Why is the filesize different when swapping audio tracks using ffmeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video-processing

I have a movie that I have encoded using Handbrake on a Mac a long time ago.  When I encoded the movie, I put the stereo audio as track 1 and the 5.1 audio as track 2.  The starting filesize is 853,320,914 bytes.  Below is the data from ffprobe.

```
ffprobe version 4.2.1-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Annabelle - Comes Home (2019).m4v':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2020-04-06T22:40:36.000000Z
    encoder         : HandBrake 1.1.2 2018090500
  Duration: 01:46:04.86, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1072 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 476.986000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 1
    Chapter #0:1: start 476.986000, end 933.608000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 2
    Chapter #0:2: start 933.608000, end 1441.449000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 3
    Chapter #0:3: start 1441.449000, end 1976.358000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 4
    Chapter #0:4: start 1976.358000, end 2579.753000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 5
    Chapter #0:5: start 2579.753000, end 3149.030000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 6
    Chapter #0:6: start 3149.030000, end 3726.941000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 7
    Chapter #0:7: start 3726.941000, end 3973.520000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 8
    Chapter #0:8: start 3973.520000, end 4504.676000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 9
    Chapter #0:9: start 4504.676000, end 4904.409000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0:10: start 4904.409000, end 5421.592000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0:11: start 5421.592000, end 5998.001000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0:12: start 5998.001000, end 6364.075000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 13
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 720x360 [SAR 32:27 DAR 64:27], 519 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-06T22:40:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 162 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-06T22:40:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : Stereo
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-06T22:40:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : Surround
    Side data:
      audio service type: main
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-06T22:40:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
Unsupported codec with id 100359 for input stream 3
```

My goal is to swap the stereo audio track with the 5.1 audio track and make the 5.1 audio track the default without having to reencode.  To do this, I used the following command:

ffmpeg -i "Annabelle - Comes Home (2019)/Annabelle - Comes Home (2019)_old.m4v" -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:a:0 -disposition:a:0 default -disposition:a:1 none -c copy "Annabelle - Comes Home (2019)/Annabelle - Comes Home (2019).m4v"

Everything works as it should, I think anyways as I didn't get any errors...

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.1-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Annabelle - Comes Home (2019)/Annabelle - Comes Home (2019)_old.m4v':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2020-04-06T22:40:36.000000Z
    encoder         : HandBrake 1.1.2 2018090500
  Duration: 01:46:04.86, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1072 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 476.986000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 1
    Chapter #0:1: start 476.986000, end 933.608000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 2
    Chapter #0:2: start 933.608000, end 1441.449000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 3
    Chapter #0:3: start 1441.449000, end 1976.358000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 4
    Chapter #0:4: start 1976.358000, end 2579.753000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 5
    Chapter #0:5: start 2579.753000, end 3149.030000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 6
    Chapter #0:6: start 3149.030000, end 3726.941000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 7
    Chapter #0:7: start 3726.941000, end 3973.520000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 8
    Chapter #0:8: start 3973.520000, end 4504.676000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 9
    Chapter #0:9: start 4504.676000, end 4904.409000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0:10: start 4904.409000, end 5421.592000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0:11: start 5421.592000, end 5998.001000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0:12: start 5998.001000, end 6364.075000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 13
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 720x360 [SAR 32:27 DAR 64:27], 519 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-06T22:40:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 162 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-06T22:40:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : Stereo
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-06T22:40:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : Surround
    Side data:
      audio service type: main
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-06T22:40:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
[ipod @ 0x7faff0014000] track 1: codec frame size is not set
Output #0, ipod, to 'Annabelle - Comes Home (2019)/Annabelle - Comes Home (2019).m4v':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 476.986000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 1
    Chapter #0:1: start 476.986000, end 933.608000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 2
    Chapter #0:2: start 933.608000, end 1441.449000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 3
    Chapter #0:3: start 1441.449000, end 1976.358000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 4
    Chapter #0:4: start 1976.358000, end 2579.753000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 5
    Chapter #0:5: start 2579.753000, end 3149.030000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 6
    Chapter #0:6: start 3149.030000, end 3726.941000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 7
    Chapter #0:7: start 3726.941000, end 3973.520000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 8
    Chapter #0:8: start 3973.520000, end 4504.676000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 9
    Chapter #0:9: start 4504.676000, end 4904.409000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0:10: start 4904.409000, end 5421.592000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0:11: start 5421.592000, end 5998.001000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0:12: start 5998.001000, end 6364.075000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 13
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 720x360 [SAR 32:27 DAR 64:27], q=2-31, 519 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-06T22:40:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-06T22:40:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : Surround
    Side data:
      audio service type: main
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 162 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-06T22:40:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : Stereo
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=152602 fps=12872 q=-1.0 Lsize=  834270kB time=01:46:04.79 bitrate=1073.8kbits/s speed= 537x    
video:403702kB audio:424714kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.706676%
```

Here is the resulting ffprobe of the new file showing it swapped the audio tracks:

```
ffprobe version 4.2.1-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Annabelle - Comes Home (2019).m4v':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V 
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 01:46:04.86, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1073 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 476.986000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 1
    Chapter #0:1: start 476.986000, end 933.608000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 2
    Chapter #0:2: start 933.608000, end 1441.449000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 3
    Chapter #0:3: start 1441.449000, end 1976.358000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 4
    Chapter #0:4: start 1976.358000, end 2579.753000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 5
    Chapter #0:5: start 2579.753000, end 3149.030000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 6
    Chapter #0:6: start 3149.030000, end 3726.941000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 7
    Chapter #0:7: start 3726.941000, end 3973.520000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 8
    Chapter #0:8: start 3973.520000, end 4504.676000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 9
    Chapter #0:9: start 4504.676000, end 4904.409000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0:10: start 4904.409000, end 5421.592000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0:11: start 5421.592000, end 5998.001000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0:12: start 5998.001000, end 6364.075000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 13
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 720x360 [SAR 32:27 DAR 64:27], 519 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Surround
    Side data:
      audio service type: main
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 162 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Stereo
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
Unsupported codec with id 100359 for input stream 3
```

What I don't understand is why is the file size different?  The resulting file is larger at 854,292,790 bytes.  Shouldn't the file sizes be the same since I literally just swapped tracks 0 and 1?

Comment: Not sure if it's a slightly different format, but I noticed that the "major_brand" on the original is "mp42", while the "major_brand" on the copy is "M4V".

Comment: Is there a better way for me to swap audio tracks while keeping everything else intact?  I wasn't trying to change anything other that swapping the audio tracks.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/29467/change-default-audio-track-of-video-file-using-ffmpeg/29490

Comment: I saw that one.  I also used this to formulate my swap: https://newbedev.com/how-do-i-swap-the-first-and-second-audio-streams-in-an-mkv-in-a-linux-based-system   I guess that's why I'm confused as to why my file sizes are different and if there was a better way to do the audio swap.

Comment: Probably a difference of muxing overhead: `muxing overhead: 0.706676%`

Comment: So, I shouldn't be worried about lose of quality, right?  I don't understand muxing overhead...

Comment: Didn't get notified of your response (use @llogan). Correct, no loss should occur.